# GetComputerName return is too short for my computer name... what to do?

Tags: c++, windows

My computer name is similar to this: "ABC12-PEACEBRINGER" (18 characters) and it's a windows xp machine although the final program also needs to run on windows 7.

When I use the following c++ code the computer name gets cut off and the return is
`ABC12-PEACEBRIN`.

```
TCHAR   MachineName[32];
DWORD   buf = 32;
GetComputerNameA(MachineName, &buf);
```

Btw. when I type `ipconfig /all` into my cmd I do get the complete computer name.

I tried some different solutions from the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) homepage but the result remains the same.

Does anyone know a solution to get a computer name of that length?!
...Changing the name is not a solution ;-)

Comment: Using `TCHAR` and proceeding to explicitly call the `*A` version of `GetComputerName` is confusing at best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NetBIOS names (which `GetComputerName` returns) are limited to 15 characters.

You likely want some other variation -- look at `GetComputerNameEx` to see your options.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: `GetComputerNameEx(ComputerNamePhysicalDnsHostname, MachineName, &buf);` solved the problem and besides: the name is now also no longer delivered in caps, which was not necessary for me but nice to have!